# Figure and axes methods in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have the following setup:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.exp(x)
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x, y)
```

I would like to add a title to the plot (or to the subplot).

I tried:

```
> fig1.title('foo')
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'title'
```

and

```
> ax1.title('foo')
 TypeError: 'Text' object is not callable
```

How can I use the object-oriented programming interface to matplotlib to set these attributes?

More generally, where can I find the hierarchy of classes in matplotlib and their corresponding methods?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

use `ax1.set_title('foo')` instead

`ax1.title` returns a `matplotlib.text.Text`object:

```
In [289]: ax1.set_title('foo')
Out[289]: <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x939cdb0>

In [290]: print ax1.title
Text(0.5,1,'foo')
```

You can also add a centered title to the figure when there are multiple `AxesSubplot`:

```
In [152]: fig, ax=plt.subplots(1, 2)
     ...: fig.suptitle('title of subplots')
Out[152]: <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x94cf650>
```

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu 13.10, ipython 1.1.0, python 2.7.5, matplotlib 1.2.1) I need to do a 'fig1.show()' after the 'ax1.set_title(...) call for it to take visible effect.  My guess is this is standard behaviour.

Comment: @RoryYorke yep, you need to call show() by default.

Comment: FWIW, `figure` does have the `suptitle` method which allows you to put one title over multiple subplots.